# Automated way to update/deploy scheduler to vps

Tags: c#, deployment, service, windows-server-2008-r2

I created a class with a timer that will perform some actions every 10 min. However the class is updated frequently and the it must run every 10 min all day!

How can I ensure that the server is using the latest version without interrupting the schedule?

I am considering creating a windows service. It is inconvenient to update it on the server.

You have to:

1. Stop the service
2. Un-register the service
3. Uninstall service
4. Uninstall the application
5. Install new application
6. Register the new service
7. Start the new service

tl;dr: I am looking for an easy solution to deploy a windows service or another solution to the server that is simple and convenient to update.

I am considering a WCF service, but they are not made for this purpose. I believe with a WCF service you can easily publish it directly to the VPS IIS.

Maxim

Comment: When updating the underlying service, you would only need to stop it and replace the relevant assemblies(I'm assuming you are going to use the same path). Is there some reason that stopping it and replacing the assemblies could not be completed in the 10 minute window?

Comment: so I ll just have to stop service, change the dll file and start service again ? I think I can get that automated somewhat easily, still when I would use a wcf project, I would only have to click publish and it would be update it as well. (without me having to manualy upload the new dlls to the right directory)

Comment: Yes, as long as the path is identical.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TL;DR